# How to play YouTube in Background with Android Webview?

Tags: android, webview, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications, foreground-service

I want to "minimize" the application, leaving it in background doing exactly the same that when the ghostbutton mode is pressed when the user clicks a button (but don't finish it) How can I do that?

So far I'm able to create a `Activity`. I've initialize my members and load the `WebView` with "https://www.youtube.com". I'm also able to create a `Service` that lets me minimize the `Activity`, but what I want is to minimize the `Activity` that I've my `WebView` loaded. **Problem** When the `Activity` paused, `WebView` is also paused.

**What I want now.**

1. A ghost mode -> basically minimizing this current activity with
   system overlay and showing notification for media controls that can
   play/resume and exit from the ghost mode.
2. A `MainActivity` that is visible to me and only becomes the sevice
   and show me 
   `Notification` control after pressing *ghostmode* btn

**What I've handled so far**

Screen orientation, meaning `Activity` doesn't recreate the `WebView`. If I'm watching some video,it just pause the video on screen orientation.

**What answers I want**

3. Can I make my current `Activity` to become a service?
4. If no, can I just create a `SplashActivity` that opens this make `MainActivity` and make this `Service` on button click.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".Services.GhostModeService" />

 android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(TAG,"classmain-> onCreate");
    initializeM();
    settingWebview();
    initializeNavigationTab();
    myoutube.loadUrl(URL);
    ghostModeServiceIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,GhostModeService.class);
}
```

**These are my settings.**

```
private void settingWebview() {
        myoutube.setWebViewClient(new Myyoutube());
        myoutube.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        myoutube.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        myoutube.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        myoutube.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
            myoutube.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(true);
        myoutube.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myoutube.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    }
```

**GhostmodeService**

```
 private WindowManager mWindowManager;
 private View mGhostmode;

@Override
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Log.d(TAG,"classghostservice-> onCreate()");
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mGhostmode = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_ghostmode,null,false);

    //setting the layout parameters
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            500,
            500,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.x=0;
    params.y=0;
    params.gravity=Gravity.END | Gravity.BOTTOM;


    //getting windows services and adding the floating view to it
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mWindowManager.addView(mGhostmode, params);

}
```

Method that create my notification. This notification resumes the `MainActivity`.

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG,"classghostservice-> onstartCommand()");
        foregroundNotification(1);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED] After a week I'm able to answer this long awaited question of **How to Run Youtube In background using Webview**. Yes, webview requires UI to run we can't run it in background using service, even if you do find a you way, you will still get in issues.

The clever tricks are as following:

1. Yes, you need to add `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` because you want to make a floating window that stays on top of other apps.
2. Let's say you have asked for permission and ready to start `MainActivity`, at this point forget about `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` instead you need to add your layout in `WindowManager` using `windowManager.addView(yourLayout, yourWindowParams);`

**activity_main.xml**

In my layout my parent layout was DrawerLayout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent".....
```

So, I had to define my member variable as follows

```
private static DrawerLayout windowMain;
```

**MainActivity**

```
 windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
 inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 windowMain = (DrawerLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
```

1. Now the main part is by using this `windowMain`, you have to call

   ```
    findViewById()
   ```

**eg**

```
windowMain.findViewById(R.id.btn);
windowMain.findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

3. You also need to define its `WindowManager.LayoutParams`. Initializing params.

   ```
   WindowManager.LayoutParams=expandParams
   expandParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON|
                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
           PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
   expandParams.gravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.TOP;
   expandParams.x = 0;
   expandParams.y = 0;
   ```
4. Finally, you need to add windowMain and its params into windowManager by

   ```
     windowManager.addView(windowMain, expandParams);
   ```

Everything is done to make a window that floats around and take whole of your screen, then do what you need to do like loading `URL` in webview using `wv.loadURL(url)`. This ensures that we have loaded our webview inside a window and **we just need to update the params of our `windowMain` so that it minimize it or even completely disappear by setting `w:0` and `h:0` instead of `MATCH_PARENT`**

You can have a `btn_ghost` that updatesthe window like:

```
windowManager.updateViewLayout(windowMain, ghostParams);
```

5. Lastly, when we've created this created we can call `moveTaskToBack(true);` this will stop out activity move it to task, becuase we don't need it. When finishing this activity that was created but stopped we must remove our `windowMain` .

   ```
     windowManager.removeView(windowMain);
     finish()
   ```

Comment: Kindly fix your sample code. "WindowManager.LayoutParams=expandParams". Does not end with semicolon and couldnt be an assignment